# Graph of a matrix and a positive power for the the matrix

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

A graph has a path from node $j$ to node $i$ if and only if its adjacency matrix has a positive element $(i,j)$ of $A^k$ for some integer $k.$

A proof for this statement will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint.*  In fact there are $A_{ij}^m$ walks of length at most $m$ from $i$ to $j$.  The inductive proof of this is pretty much identical to the one you're asking asking for, and your question follows a corollary.

> *Hint 2.* Use $A_{ij}^m=\sum_{k=1}^n A_{ik}^{m-1}A_{kj}$.

Comment: I think you mean walks of length exactly $m$.

Answer (score 1):

You may prove by mathematical induction. The base case is trivial. For the $k$-th iteration, note that $(A^k)_{ij}\not=0$ iff $(A^{k-1})_{i\ell}$ and $A_{\ell j}$ are both nonzero for some index $\ell$.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove by induction. See Section 2.1 of [this](http://www.math.ryerson.ca/~danziger/professor/MTH607/Handouts/matrices.pdf)